# Trying to understand multilinear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently trying to teach myself a bit of linear algebra in preparation for college, but I get stuck on the concept of multi linear maps. I can't seem to understand what exactly multilinearity is and how to apply it to other concepts. The resources I use for learning are mostly YouTube videos and a book called "Multivariable Calculus and Differential Geometry" by Gerrard Walschap. Is there an easily comprehensible resource or example?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know what a scalar product on $\mathbb R^2$ is?

Comment: The determinant is also a good example of a multilinear function.

Comment: [My notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A map $f:V_1\times\ldots\times V_n\to W$, defined on the cartesian product of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces $V_i$, $i=1, \dots ,n$ and taking values in an $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $W$ is said to be multilinear if it is linear on each component, that is
$$f(\ldots, \lambda v+\mu w,\ldots)=\lambda f(\ldots, v,\ldots)+\mu f(\ldots,w,\ldots)$$
for every $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{F}$, for every $v,w\in V_i$ and for every $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

Comment: Thank you for the short and concise answer!